# Adding more languages in Wikibase

Tags: mediawiki, multilingual, mediawiki-extensions, wikibase

I'm attempting to add more languages into a custom Wikibase installation as shown here: [image]

In the area where "Language" is I should be able to list other languages. I've clicked "Configure" which links out to the general MediaWiki help for configuring languages (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Wikibase/Configuring_languages). However, it doesn't seem to explain how to do it on a custom installation.

I did a bit of digging online and discovered that maybe installing the Universal Language Selector extension was the way to do it, but I've installed it (and verified the install) and it still doesn't seem to be possible.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just click on "In more languages". Or are you trying to add a language not currently supported by MediaWiki?

Comment: @Tgr so that's just a dropdown for the list, it doesn't do anything. The languages are supported in MediaWiki and Wikibase it just won't let me add them in the box itself.

Comment: Currently wikibase will only expose so many languages to you. You can switch your language to see other languages. Wikidata also currently has a gadget that allows users to interact with labels etc in all languages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure if I understand your question.
Are you maybe looking for https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:SetLabel ?
It lets you set the Label for any Item or Property in any supported language.